# Why do I get the "Error: non-payable method cannot override value" when both the function and constructor are payable?

Tags: solidity, payable

I have ran into a strange problem. I get an 'Error: non-payable method cannot override value' when I try to send some ethereum to the smart contract via the transfer function. Here is the smart contract logic excerpt:

```
constructor() payable {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }
function deposit(address _seller) external payable returns(bytes32) {

   require(msg.value > 0.1 ether, "Value of the deposit must be more than 0.1 ether"); 
}
```

And this is the UI code excerpt:

```
function blockchainTalk(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  contract.deposit("0xF025B4AC25D5DC1FfD77B099a31ddc269D55c039", {gasLimit: 5000000, value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0")});
}
```

However, I am not able to transfer to my smart contract, as I get the "Error: non-payable method cannot override value".

Please help me out <3

**Edit:
Upon request, sharing the full contract:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Escrow {

  address owner;

  struct Deposit {
      uint256 depositAmount;
      address buyer;
      address seller;
      bool executed;
  }

  constructor() payable {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  mapping(bytes32 => Deposit) public depositByHash; 

  event DepositMade(address buyerAddress, address sellerAddress, uint depositAmount, bytes32 hash);
  
  function deposit(address _seller) external payable returns(bytes32) {

    require(msg.value > 0.1 ether, "Value of the deposit must be more than 0.1 ether"); 

    bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encode(msg.value, block.timestamp, _seller)); 

    Deposit storage _deposit = depositByHash[hash]; 

    _deposit.depositAmount = msg.value; 

    _deposit.buyer = msg.sender;
    
    _deposit.seller = _seller;  

    emit DepositMade(msg.sender, _seller, msg.value, hash);

    return hash; 
  }

  function releaseDepositToBuyer(bytes32 hash) external returns(bool) {

    require(msg.sender == depositByHash[hash].buyer, "Only maker of the deposit can release deposit.");

    require(depositByHash[hash].executed == false, "The function can only be executed once.");

    payable(depositByHash[hash].seller).transfer(depositByHash[hash].depositAmount);

    return depositByHash[hash].executed = true;
  }

  function divineIntervention(address payable _to, uint _amount) external payable {

    require(
      msg.sender == owner,
      "This function can only be called by the creator of the contract"
    );

    // This might be unsafe against re-entrancy attack. 
    // Possible there is a safer alternative.
    
    _to.transfer(_amount);
  }
}
```

And here is the full React App code (the contract is deployed to a local Hardhat node):

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { ethers } from "ethers";

function App() {

const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
const signer = provider.getSigner()
const contractAddress = "0x5fbdb2315678afecb367f032d93f642f64180aa3"

const ABI = [
  "function deposit(address _seller)"
];

const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, ABI, signer);

async function isConnected() {
  const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({method: 'eth_accounts'});       
  if (accounts.length) {
     console.log(`You're connected to: ${accounts[0]}`);
  } else {
     console.log("Metamask is not connected");
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  async function connectWallet() {
  await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
  }
  connectWallet()
    .catch(console.error)
  isConnected()

function blockchainTalk(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  contract.deposit("0xF025B4AC25D5DC1FfD77B099a31ddc269D55c039", {gasLimit: 5000000, value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0")});
}
}
```

Comment: How was `deposit` declared in the base contract? Is it also `payable`?

Comment: Yes sir, I did include the deposit declaration in my question: ```function deposit(address _seller) external payable returns(bytes32)```

Comment: Can you share the whole contract? or at least some that could be compiled and tested to reproduce the error.

Comment: @Ismael updated the question to include the full smart contract and React app logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your ABI is corrupted, make sure your abi is correct and matches your contract

Comment: yes that ABI is off upon your edit thank you

Comment: Indeed, I needed to include "payable" in the ABI! It's the first time I'm using ABI, I thought human readable ABI does not need me to include "payable" in it and that it is enough to only have it in the smart contract!

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to receive `ether` you have to have this

```
 receive() external payable{}
```